# flipping through images on mousemove

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to flip through a stack of images using mousemove function by changing z-index property of an image relevant to mouse position. I'm getting console error and don't know what causes it. I put down few comments within a code to make it a bit more clear. I'm just starting with js, it can be a very simple mistake.

```
    var $images = $('#images'),  // caching elements
    $img = $('img', $images),
    l = $img.length;  

$('#images').mousemove(function(e){
    var xPos = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    w = $(this).width() / l;
    xPos = Math.floor(xpos / w);  //setting xPos variable equal to the mouse X position.

    $img.css("z-index","0"); //assigning images z-index value to 0
    if (xPos >= 0 && xPos < l) {
        $img[xPos].css("z-index","1"); //changing 'current' (image relevant to xPos) z-index value to 1 !!!console error 'undefined'!!!
    }

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0qubpa7a/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be traced back to this line:

```
$img[xPos].css("z-index","1");
```

This is because you are treating `$img[xPos]` as a jQuery object, but it actually return the HTML node instead. You should go for:

```
$img.eq(xPos).css("z-index","1");
```

Fixed it :) check the fixed fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/0qubpa7a/4/

p/s: I also recommend declaring variables with the `var` statement, just to be safe. Also, avoid overwriting the value of `xPos`, instead, assign a new variable :)